# shifting the repeater control row up or down on button click without postback(using javascript / jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, repeater

I want to reorder the repeater control rows(whose data has come from a data table) using the UP DOWN buttons without postback.
As postback takes a lot of time for each UP / DOWN movement.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your post is tagged jquery-ui. Obtaining the desired behaviour should be fairly easy with http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ What have you tried ? Where is your issue exactly ? In saving the resulting order ?

Comment: the issue is not in saving, the issue is in reordering, i will try your suggestion, i havent used jqueryui so far.... can it not be dont using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you .
[tabel sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)
[Demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)

Comment: @swetha , can you provide your example (as jsFiddle or plunckr) ??

Comment: I have not yet created any Java script. I am not sure if this reordering is possible, so still looking for options.

Comment: create jsfiddle or pluncr of your code only , it does't matter working or not .

Comment: I dont know anything about jsfiddle or pluncr.